# Overridden RabbitSourceConfiguration (app starters) does not work with Spring Cloud Edgware

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm testing an upgrade of my Spring Cloud DataFlow services from Spring Cloud Dalston.SR4/Spring Boot 1.5.9 to Spring Cloud Edgware/Spring Boot 1.5.9. Some of my services extend source (or sink) components from the app starters. I've found this does not work with Spring Cloud Edgware.

For example, I have overridden `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.rabbit.source.RabbitSourceConfiguration` and bound my app to my overridden version. This has previously worked with Spring Cloud versions going back almost a year.

With Edgware, I get the following (whether the app is run standalone or within dataflow):

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field channels in org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.rabbit.source.RabbitSourceConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source' in your configuration.
```

I get the same behaviour with the 1.3.0.RELEASE and 1.2.0.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit.

I override RabbitSourceConfiguration so I can set a header mapper on the AmqpInboundChannelAdapter, and also to perform a connectivity test prior to starting up the container.

My subclass is bound to the Spring Boot application with `@EnableBinding(HeaderMapperRabbitSourceConfiguration.class)`. A cutdown version of my subclass is:

```
public class HeaderMapperRabbitSourceConfiguration extends RabbitSourceConfiguration {

    public HeaderMapperRabbitSourceConfiguration(final MyHealthCheck healthCheck,
                                                 final MyAppConfig config) {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter() {
        final AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = super.adapter();
        adapter.setHeaderMapper(new NotificationHeaderMapper(config));

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container() {
        if (config.performConnectivityCheckOnStartup()) {

            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("Attempting connectivity with ...");
            }
            final Health health = healthCheck.health();
            if (health.getStatus() == Status.DOWN) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to connect .....");
                throw new UnableToLoginException("Unable to connect ...");
            } else if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("Connectivity established with ...");
            }
        }

        return super.container();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `RabbitSourceConfiguration`.

Comment: I've added the config class to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should never do stuff like `healthCheck.health();` within a `@Bean` definition. The application context is not yet fully baked or started; it may, or may not, work depending on the order that beans are created.

If you want to prevent the app from starting, add a bean that implements `SmartLifecycle`, put the bean in a late phase (high value) so it's started after everything else. Then put your code in `start()`. `autStartup` must be true.

In this case, it's being run before the stream infrastructure has created the channel.

Some ordering might have changed from the earlier release but, in any case, performing activity like this in a `@Bean` definition is dangerous.

You just happened to be lucky before.

**EDIT**

I just noticed your `@EnableBinding` is wrong; it should be `Source.class`. I can't see how that would ever have worked - that's what creates the bean for the `channels` field of type `Source`.

This works fine for me after updating stream and the binder to 1.3.0.RELEASE...

```
@Configuration
public class MySource extends RabbitSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter() {
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = super.adapter();
        adapter.setHeaderMapper(new MyMapper());
        return adapter;
    }


}
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

If that doesn't work, please edit the question to show your POM.

Comment: Ok, point taken on the health check, but that doesn't answer my original question.I can have an empty override of RabbitSourceConfiguration and still Edgware complains about finding no Source. Indeed, I have other similar cases with overridden app starter sources and sinks (with no health checks) which now all fail with Edgware. The health check is a red herring.

Comment: That works! I had tried binding the main application class to Source.class but that didn't work on its own. What has worked is your example. Bind app class to Source.class *and* mark the subclass config as @Configuration. Thanks for your help.